# DataFrame game: return all records that match with the first lower or equal datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Who's in for a nice pandas DataFrame game?
I have following puzzle but can't come to a solution:

Imagine following pandas DataFrame `holdings_df`

```
      datetime    instrument     quantity
0   2021-07-06          $USD  2000.000000
1   2021-07-30          $USD -1841.278610
2   2021-07-30  US3160928731    12.000000
3   2021-07-30  US46137V2410     7.000000
4   2021-07-30  US46137V6056     3.000000
5   2021-07-30  US4642861458     9.000000
6   2021-07-30  US4642865251     9.368500
7   2021-07-30  US4642874329     6.486500
8   2021-07-30  US46434G8556     3.000000
9   2021-07-30  US46434V4234     3.000000
10  2021-07-30  US97717W5215     6.000000
11  2021-08-01          $USD    -1.727408
12  2021-08-02          $USD     1.178727
```

I need a function that can do the following:

- find all the records from the datetime that is closest or equal to certain datetime x and return the instrument and quantity values for those records.

For instance in this case. When x would be 2021-07-20 it should return $USD  2000.000000 and when x is 2021-07-30 it should return

```
        $USD -1841.278610
US3160928731    12.000000
US46137V2410     7.000000
US46137V6056     3.000000
US4642861458     9.000000
US4642865251     9.368500
US4642874329     6.486500
US46434G8556     3.000000
US46434V4234     3.000000
US97717W5215     6.000000
```

I tried with following function (where x = current_datetime)

```
holdings_df.set_index("datetime")
holdings_df.iloc[holdings_df.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp(current_datetime),method="backfill")]
```

Which results in

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'
```

Is my datetime from type int? (already tried `holdings_df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(holdings_df["datetime"])` )

Comment: Please define the closest ? How much duration do you refer to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case we can just condition select then, `drop_duplicates`

```
n = pd.to_datetime('2021-07-20')
df = df.sort_values('datetime')
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
df[df.datetime<=n].drop_duplicates('instrument',keep='last')
Out[10]: 
    datetime instrument  quantity
0 2021-07-06       $USD    2000.0
```